# In the Mobile Site Question List, the "Unanswered" filter does not work

Tags: bug, status-declined, mobile-web

If you select "Unanswered" from the query list at the mobile site, it does not work properly.

This "Unanswered" option is not present in SO.en, and will be displayed as a choice in MSE and SO.ja (and others).

[Bug report on SO.ja meta](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3524)

---

**SO.ja**

[image]

**MSE**

[image]

**SO.en**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

> [image: screenshot of drop down list]

In Safari the “Unanswered” option is displayed, but the page is set to “Votes” whenever I try to select it. It doesn’t matter if I’m logged in or not.

All of the other options work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

We marked this request [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined) because we're not prioritizing work on mobile views. We have been making more and more areas of the site mobile responsive and eventually (no timeline or official plan yet) plan to deprecate mobile views.